# PluginNotFoundException on drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "impact_map_countries" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\rest\Plugin\Type\ResourcePluginManager are: dblog, file:upload, entity:block, entity:block" etc........

Tried truncating all cache tables via phpmyadmin. but no result

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a plugin (which was provided by some module custom or contrib) called `"impact_map_countries"` That got removed.

Also try `drush cr` as some of the cache might not be in the database. (Some bootstrap and Twig for example is in `sites/default/files/php`)